# How to work with select input with data coming from a simple relational db model

Tags: forms, angularjs

I'm using Angularjs plugged into a API which retrieves data from a mysqlk normal relational db.

Let's say I have this simple data model in my bdd:

```
table car:
  id,
  type_id

table type:
  id,
  label
```

I have a API which retrieves the data from DB to have the list of cars and the static labels from db:

```
http://myapi/car/
response :
   {[{id:1, type_id:2}, {id:2, type_id:3}]}

http://myapi/carstaticlabel/
response :
   {[{id:1, label:convertible}, {id:2, label:limousine}, {id:3, label:pickup}]}
```

**My aim is first to display a list of cars with the type label and then, open a dialog and being able to show a form with preloaded values of the selected car:**

rendered list of cars :

```
1 convertible
2 pickup
```

rendered form for edited car whose id is 1:
select the type of car:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">convertible</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">limousine</option>
  <option value="3">pickup</option>
</select>
```

---

I have tried different approaches but none is elegant

**Solution 1**

for the list of cars
change my API and make the join directly between car and type to get the list with label:

```
http://myapi/car/
response :
   {[{id:1, type_id:2, type:{[id:2, label:limousine]}}, {id:2, type_id:3, type:{[id:3, label:pickup]}}]}
```

then I just assign in the form : car.id and car['type']['label']

ISSUE: each car will contain repeated information (label) >> bloated info

for the edit form:
I pass the json of selected car to the form and set default values:

```
<p>type: <select ng-model="car.type"  ng-options="type.label for type in type_list" required></select></p>
```

MY ISSUE with that:

when I submit the form, I don't get the type_id directly, I get the car.type object instead, so I need to painfully translate it into an id to post into the database.
To convert I have to go into the car.type object and retrieve the object inside and then retrieve its id... very unelegant.

---

**Solution 2**

make the "join" inside angular by working with arrays.

ISSUE: very hard to default values in the form later on

---

**I'm lost, what is usually the best practice to achieve that simple task?**

Comment: have you tried using the advanced parts of ng-option that allow you define a key as well as a label such as `label for (key , value) in object`

Comment: I have tried, but still I have a problem for getting back the data.
For now, I finally used angular filters on the type table object to render the "ID values".
But I am sure it is not the best way. But it works at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`select as label for value in array`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) syntax for array data sources. Your example have complex data structure which is array of objects. So you need something like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedId"
        ng-options="x.id as x.label for x in response">
</select>
```

I created little example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ycyd1g?p=preview) to demonstrate proposed solution.

Comment: THanks! I think it was not working in the past, for the version of angular I was using. Now, in 1.2, it is for sure.

Comment: any other way for some repeated value max 5 times then create new array and remove that value from array? I HAVE THIS KIND OF ARRAY: ["info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.specificAllergy", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition", "info.existingMedicalCondition"]



I want : ["info.specificAllergy", "info.existingMedicalCondition"]
but if "info.existingMedicalCondition" only four times than 
I want ["info.specificAllergy"]